# How to change an argument programmatically if connection error?

Tags: python, connection

I am calling an API. While making requests I hit the maximum number of tries and I get a connection error. I would like to edit the url programmatically by incrementing the number in the url. I do know how to change the arguments programmatically but not sure how to change/increment an argument when I hit connection error.

My language of usage is Python and I am using requests library.

Code Snippet 
    `Libraries importing 
       from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
       import requests
       from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError`

````
```def make_request(data , id=None):
     url = "http://server001.net:8080/?id="
     result = {}
     if id:
       response = requests.get(url +id , auth=HTTPBasicAuth('uname', 'pass'))
       return response
     else :
       for line in data:
         try:
           response = requests.get(url +line , auth=HTTPBasicAuth('uname', 'pass'))
            result = html_parser2(response)
            if result:
                write_csv(result)
            else:
                pass
         except ConnectionError as e:
           print (e)```
````

Expected output 
    `url = "http://server001.net:8080/?id="
       url_edited = "http://server002.net:8080/?id="`
Only if I hit the maximum number of tries, i.e I get an exception or 
else keep requesting the same url.

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to enclose the `try..except` block with a `while` loop.
Besides, may be you should put your first `requests.get` into `try..except` block too.
Also try to avoid multiple unrelated operations in one `try..except` block, i.e. execute `write_csv` after successful connection only.

```py
def make_request(data , id=None):
    url = 'http://server001.net:8080/?id={}'
    connection_failed = False
    response = None
    if id:
        try:
            response = requests.get(url.format(id) , auth=HTTPBasicAuth('uname', 'pass'))
        except ConnectionError as e:
            print('id = {}, e: {}'.format(id, e))
    else:
        for line in data:
            while not connection_failed:
                try:
                    response = requests.get(url.format(line) , auth=HTTPBasicAuth('uname', 'pass'))
                except ConnectionError as e:
                    connection_failed = True
                    print('line = {}, e: {}'.format(id, e))
                else:
                    result = html_parser2(response)
                    if result:
                        write_csv(result)
    return response
```

```py
def make_request(data , id=None):
    url = 'http://server001.net:8080/?id={}'
    response = None
    if id:
        try:
            response = requests.get(url.format(id) , auth=HTTPBasicAuth('uname', 'pass'))
        except ConnectionError as e:
            print('id = {}, e: {}'.format(id, e))
    else:
        for line in data:
            try:
                response = requests.get(url.format(line) , auth=HTTPBasicAuth('uname', 'pass'))
            except ConnectionError as e:
                print('line = {}, e: {}'.format(id, e))
            else:
                result = html_parser2(response)
                if result:
                    write_csv(result)
                break
    return response
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your code is much cleaner than mine but I wanted to increment the server number in url if error.

Comment: Oh... Ok, it seems I misunderstood you. You can try a new version then. Just take each `line` in `data` sequentially and exit the loop if there wasn't a ConnectionError. I believe you can easily merge two versions by yourself if you need to send multiple requests for each line in `data`